# How do you get the original windows button texture in Java

Tags: java

I was just wondering if there is any way to get the regular windows buttons to work in java. For me JButtons don't look very professional and the AWT Buttons look to old school, so i just wanted to know if there was anyway to use them? If not could you send me to an external api that would allow me to use them, if one even exists.

Comment: If you use SWT/RCP you will get the native look and feel on all the platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```